# Tycho does not use target file from eclipse-target-definition project without version in the pom

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho, target-platform

I have a problem with the Maven/Tycho mechanism to resolve dependencies from a .target file. I followed the information on https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Target_files, but do not get the expected results. Here are some facts:

Target file:

```xml
<target name="Eclipse Kepler Target" sequenceNumber="1424335573">
<locations>
    <location includeMode="slicer" includeAllPlatforms="false" includeSource="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" type="InstallableUnit">
        <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.sdk.feature.group"  version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.transaction.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.validation.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.workspace.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.workspace.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.eef.sdk-feature.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.draw2d.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.gef.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.notation.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.acceleo.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.acceleo.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ocl.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ocl.source.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <repository id="kepler" location="http://korvm016.apac.bosch.com/updatesites/thirdparty/eclipse_4.3_kepler/"/>
    </location>
    <location includeMode="slicer" includeAllPlatforms="false" includeSource="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" type="InstallableUnit">
        <unit id="com.google.inject" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="com.google.inject.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="com.google.inject.assistedinject.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="com.google.inject.assistedinject" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="com.google.inject.multibindings.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="com.google.inject.multibindings" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="com.google.guava" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="com.google.guava.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="javax.activation" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="javax.activation.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.aopalliance" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.cli" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.cli.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.collections" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.collections.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.exec" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.exec.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.httpclient" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.httpclient.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.io" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.io.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.lang" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.apache.commons.lang.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.junit" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.junit.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.core.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.core" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.generator.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.generator" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.integration.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.integration" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.library.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.library" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.text.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest.text" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.hamcrest" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.mockito" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.mockito.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.objenesis" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.objenesis.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.classic" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.classic.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.core" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.core.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.slf4j" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="ch.qos.logback.slf4j.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.api" version="0.0.0"/>
        <unit id="org.slf4j.api.source" version="0.0.0"/>
        <repository id="orbit" location="http://korvm016.apac.bosch.com/updatesites/thirdparty/orbit-buildrepo-R20140525021250/"/>
     </location>
</locations>
</target>
```

The pom-File for the target module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.etas.congra.releng</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.etas.congra.releng.targetplatform</artifactId>
    <packaging>eclipse-target-definition</packaging>
</project>
```

I do not have a version in here, because I found a page in the web which told the story that a version in the pom for the eclipse-target-packaging does not work and in fact, specifying a version resulted in not resolving the following configuration in the parent pom used for all other maven modules:

```xml
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <artifact>
                <groupId>com.etas.congra.releng</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.etas.congra.releng.targetplatform</artifactId>
                <relativePath>../../releng/com.etas.congra.releng.targetplatform/pom.xml</relativePath>
            </artifact>
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

With this in place I get the following error message during the maven build:

```text
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: com.etas.congra.releng:com.etas.congra.log:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\ConGra_IDE_Luna_win64\git\congra\plugins\com.etas.congra.log\pom.xml
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: com.etas.congra.releng:com.etas.congra.log:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\ConGra_IDE_Luna_win64\git\congra\plugins\com.etas.congra.log\pom.xml
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] Cannot complete the request.  Generating details.
[INFO] {osgi.ws=win32, osgi.os=win32, osgi.arch=x86_64, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.etas.congra.log 0.1.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.etas.congra.log 0.1.0.qualifier requires 'bundle ch.qos.logback.classic 1.0.7' but it could not be found
[ERROR]
```

It cannot resolve dependencies to artifacts from the target file, although the target works properly in the Eclipse workspace and if all repositories mentioned in the target files are expressed as repository tags in the pom file, the build also works.

Has anybody an idea what is wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure a target-platform-configuration artifact where either the `groupId`, `artifactId`, or `version` is missing, Tycho silently ignores this configuration. This [is a bug in Tycho](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460399) - it should fail with a clear error message instead.

So you need to reference the `eclipse-target-definition` module with a version. In case you have a project setup which uses the same version in every module, you can use `${project.version}` for this (to avoid manual work when you are using the [tycho-versions-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-release/tycho-versions-plugin/set-version-mojo.html) which [currently doesn't update the target-platform-configuration](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371884)). If some of the projects which inherit the target-platform-configuration from your parent POM use a different version, you need to specify the target file with an explicit version. (Background: Variables in POMs are expanded after inheritance, so `${project.version}` expands to the version of the child project and not to the version of the parent POM containing the configuration.)

Answer (score -3):

same question asked and answered on the tycho-user mailing list:

https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg06323.html

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers, but also copy the essence of the answer from the linked source into the answer.